# Update Set From not affecting any rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

The Update Query is as follows:

```
UPDATE  Cust_Site
  SET   Cust_Site.Name= H.Name
FROM    Header H 
INNER JOIN Cust_Site S 
    ON   H.Name <> S.Name
    AND H.ID = S.ID
    AND H.Country = S.Country;
```

Whenever I run this, I affect 150 rows. But even if I use COMMIT, the rows in Cust_Site are not changed at all.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Without seeing your data it tough to tell. But this looks suspicious `ON H.BillTo_Name <> S.Site_Name;` Seems like you'd have a lot of matches for BillTo_Name not being equal to Site_Name

Comment: That join condition doesn't make sense as it isn't linking rows in a 1:1 fashion as the names that don't match could link and thus this could have unexpected results.  What other columns in those tables could be linked so that the name is properly updated?

Comment: Okay... an updated query. How are you validating that the rows in `Cust_Site` are not changed? Are there any triggers on the table? Is there any process updating the rows automatically in the background?

Comment: I have a query that does a select just on Cust_Site.Name and H.Name with the same FROM statement. There are no other processes on the background.

Comment: I have deleted my answer since @ConradFrix pointed out the table alias wasn't the issue. I'm glad we are now looking at a more reasonable join condition. Which means I don't have an answer to explain what is going on.

Comment: You and me man. To be honest, I am using this same syntax structure to update other tables in the same database. So I'm half-way thinking that the problem might be with the table itself?. I recreated the table and its still doing it.

Comment: Not really a solution but I would anyway start the `ON` clause with both `equal` conditions and throw in the `<>` at the end. The other way round you usually evaluate at least 2 conditions per row rather than exiting after the first one

Answer (score 3):

Try outputting the inserted and deleted rows for the update statement to see what the changes are:

```
UPDATE  Cust_Site
  SET   Cust_Site.Name= H.Name
OUTPUT deleted.Name, inserted.Name, inserted.*
FROM    Header H 
INNER JOIN Cust_Site S 
    ON H.ID = S.ID
    AND H.Country = S.Country
    AND H.Name <> S.Name
```

This way you will be able to rule out the possibility that the query is actually updating stuff with the same values.

Before running the query do `@@Trancount` just in case you have any open transactions.
Make sure you're running your verification `select` on the same DB.

**UPDATE:**

One thing that occurred to me just now as a possible issue:

- Are the columns in both tables declared with the same type? (i.e. VARCHAR rather than fixed length)
- Are you sure the data in either of them doesn't contain leading/trailing whitespaces that would make the names seem different for the UPDAte stmt ? Can you trim them when comparing?

Comment: Is this a SQL 2005 and up syntax?. I should have mentioned before, but the server is SQL 2000. Would OUTPUT work on this version?

Comment: @Overseer10 - I don't believe it is - but you can get a similar functionality with temp tables, see this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/output-clause.aspx. Also, I'd suggest that you start with looking at the data returned by `SELECT * FROM    Header H 
INNER JOIN Cust_Site S 
    ON H.ID = S.ID
    AND H.Country = S.Country
    AND H.Name <> S.Name` - to see what differences to expect after the query has been run and check if everything is ok with them

Comment: For some reason the OUTPUT does not seem to work, neither creating a #temp table nor by its own. I tried using only inserted and deleted columns but for some reason OUTPUT doesn't seem to run on SQL Analyser.

Comment: @Overseer10 - have you tried running the `select` with `inner join` at all? Does it match what you would expect? Is there anything that could be rolling back your changes - any automated process ?

Comment: I've not had the chance to use SELECT on the Inner Join yet. After the help folks have provided me here, I figure the problem might not be on the query. So i'm looking at what else is running on the DB and find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written this query as a correlated subquery as follows, however this may fail with an error if the subquery returns more than one row for each cust_site row. If it does fail then that might be a clue as to why you aren't getting the results you expect.

```
UPDATE  Cust_Site
   SET  Name = (SELECT H.Name FROM Header H WHERE Name <> S.Name AND ID = S.ID AND Country = S.Country)
  FROM  Cust_Site S;
```

Comment: This might not work for my purposes, there might be more than 500 results from the sub-query

Comment: In which case you could change it to SELECT MIN(H.Name)... because it's a little bit strange to update each Cust_Site table row 500 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the

```
ON   H.Name <> S.Name
```

and move the condition to the end of the query, thus:

```
WHERE   H.Name <> S.Name
```

and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Tried, but same issue came back. The Update affects the rows but once I run the Select query the table was not updated.